# add c++ compiler, linker flags to nsight eclipse 6.5 in ubuntu

Tags: c++, ubuntu, cuda, linker, nsight

I started using nsight eclipse 6.5 with cuda 6.5 under ubuntu 14.04 for gpu development purposes. But now I'm confused with the toolchains. How to add g++ support to the project and pass linker flags that are used by certain c++ libraries.

It seems that the toolchain consists only nvcc (I can't see any g++/gcc there?)
How to put them in my project?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK I've solved it. I needed to put these flags to the nvcc compiler -> misc settings. Then it works.